# Magento2 - How to customization of the invoice pdf?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to customize invoice pdf add parent category name before product name and after child category name.

How to customization of the invoice pdf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customise invoice PDF using following way in your custom module, here I have added Parent Category Name before Product Name:

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */ -->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" />
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
</config>
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Magento/Sales/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice
{
    public function draw()
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $item = $this->getItem();
        $pdf = $this->getPdf();
        $page = $this->getPage();
        $lines = [];

        // draw Product category
        $productCat = $this->getParentCatName($item, $page);

        $productCat .= ' => ' . $item->getName();
        // draw Product name
        $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($productCat, 35, true, true), 'feed' => 35]];

        // draw SKU
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $this->string->split($this->getSku($item), 17),
            'feed' => 290,
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // draw QTY
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        // draw item Prices
        $i = 0;
        $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
        $feedPrice = 395;
        $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 170;
        foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
            if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
                // draw Price label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
                // draw Subtotal label
                $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
                $i++;
            }
            // draw Price
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['price'],
                'feed' => $feedPrice,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            // draw Subtotal
            $lines[$i][] = [
                'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
                'font' => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right',
            ];
            $i++;
        }

        // draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => 495,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];

        // custom options
        $options = $this->getItemOptions();
        if ($options) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                // draw options label
                $lines[][] = [
                    'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                    'font' => 'italic',
                    'feed' => 35,
                ];

                // Checking whether option value is not null
                if ($option['value'] !== null) {
                    if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                        $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                    } else {
                        $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                    }
                    $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                    foreach ($values as $value) {
                        $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

        $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $this->setPage($page);
    }

    /**
     * Get Parent Category Name
     */
    private function getParentCatName($item, &$page)
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productId = $item->getOrderItem()->getProductId(); //Get Product Id
        $categoryIds = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList')->getCategoryIds($productId);
        $categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
        $categoryName = $categoryCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $firstCategoryId)->getFirstItem()->getName();
        return $categoryName;
    }
}
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Magento/Sales/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Magento\Sales\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
/**
 * Draw header for item table
 *
 * @param \Zend_Pdf_Page $page
 * @return void
 */
    protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Categories => Products'), 'feed' => 35];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

        $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
        $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }

}
```

## Output

[image]

You can also add separate column for Categories, but for that you need to manage 'feed' value also, and also you can add child Categories using same way.

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. this useful for me.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: Wonderful!!! perfect answer with explanation! +1 Made my day!!! :)

Comment: Thanks @SagarPPanchal :)

Answer (score 2):

You can customize by overriding below class 
 "**AbstractPdf**" in your Module:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information.

Answer (score 1):

You have create the custom module

You want to change thee invoice pdf columns headers this file like :-

> vendor/modulename/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

And change the invoice pdf alignments right left position invoice number, invoice date etc like file :-

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php

Note :- And AbstractPdf.php file is not override your custom module so follow this code i hope help this code :-

Your custom module path:-

> vendor/modulename/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace vendor\modulename\Model\Order\Pdf;

/**
 * Sales Order Invoice PDF model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Config $pdfConfig,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Total\Factory $pdfTotalFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\ItemsFactory $pdfItemsFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Address\Renderer $addressRenderer,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($paymentData, $string, $scopeConfig, $filesystem, $pdfConfig, $pdfTotalFactory,
            $pdfItemsFactory, $localeDate, $inlineTranslation, $addressRenderer, $storeManager, $localeResolver, $data);
    }




protected function insertOrder(&$page, $obj, $putOrderId = true)
    {
        //Your code 
    }
```

Hope this help you

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information.